# Unable to debug object required error on refedit userform

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried figuring out a code to copy info from  the text box value and use a ref edit to paste that info. However I am getting an object required error on `Set rngCopy = TextBox2.Value` . Hence I need some help to why I am getting this error. My rngcopy would be textbox2.value (Name) and the rngpaste location would be the ref edit 1. This is an image for a better idea of the question[image].

This is the code

```
Private Sub PasteButton_Click()

Dim rngCopy As Range, rngPaste As Range
Dim wsPaste As Range
Dim answer As Integer
answer = TextBox1.Value
If RefEdit1.Value <> "" Then

        TextBox2.Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(answer, Sheets("L12 - Data Sheet").Range("B:E"), 2, False)
        Set rngCopy = TextBox2.Value
        Set wsPaste = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Replace(Split(TextBox2.Value, "!")(0), "'", ""))
        Set rngPaste = wsPaste.Range(Split(TextBox2.Value, "!")(1))

        rngCopy.Copy rngPaste
  Else
        MsgBox "Please select an Output range"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So you have a number of worksheet & cell addresses in the ...Data worksheet's column C? If you are returning a string that looks like an address and then splitting it up you need to treat A1 like the string it is. e.g. `Range(rngCopy).Copy`

Comment: Actually I have just one sheet. and i want to copy the text box value which is a string into a cell using  refedit  . I think the split is redundant since i used that for my previous assignment @Jeeped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edited to paste link the returned cell address

edited to allow for paste link to different sheets

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub PasteButton_Click()
Dim refRng As Range, fRng As Range

With Me
    Set refRng = getRange(.RefEdit1.Value)
    If refRng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Please select an Output range"
        .RefEdit1.SetFocus
    Else
        Set fRng = FindValue(Sheets("L12 - Data Sheet").Range("B:B"), CInt(.TextBox1.Value))
        If fRng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No match!"
            .TextBox1.SetFocus
        Else
            .TextBox2.Value = fRng.Offset(, 1).Value
            refRng.Formula = "='" & fRng.Parent.Name & "'!" & fRng.Offset(, 1).address
        End If
    End If
End With

End Sub

Function FindValue(rngToSearchIn As Range, valueToFind As Variant) As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set FindValue = rngToSearchIn.Find(what:=valueToFind, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function getRange(address As String) As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set getRange = Range(address)
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

where you first make sure that the user input in `RefEdit1` control addresses a valid range since, oddly, the `RefEdit` control allows **any** input..

Comment: Isit possible to incorporate a paste link to this code?

Comment: @Niva: please add more info about what you mean with "incorporate a paste link to this code".

Comment: is it possible to paste link the cell that has been pasted via refedit and the location of textbox2.value? This is so that everytime i paste content through refedit.. and if i make any changes on Sheets("L12-Data Sheet"), it will auto amend

Comment: the code works on the same sheet but not when the pasted data is on another sheet. Lets say i key in the seat number and the name comes out.. when i paste it on the same data sheet where the data has been retrieved, the pastelink works. When i paste it on another sheet, the value becomes 0

Comment: Hi sorry for the trouble. it perfectly works now except that when i key in seat numbers that are strings eg.146A. the code does not work due to the CInt code on Setfrng=... (line 10) is there any solution for that?

Comment: remove the `CInt` thing in the `Set fRng = ...` statement